# Loss of RGB in Exported Raster to TIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have terrain raster images (jpg format) that I open in QGIS (latest version). I georeference the images (all 4 corner coordinates) then export them as a rendered image (tiff). When done, the images have all lost the original colors of the terrain and are now a blue-green tint when I run/view them in OSG Earth Viewer (from an ".earth file).

How do I keep the raster's original rgb values when exporting to a geotiff?

Comment: Check first with gdalinfo or with QGIS layer properties if the original image is RGB or single band image with color palette.

Comment: Thanks Kadir - Gdalinfo lists the jpg as having 3 bands (rgb).

Comment: What if you open the exported image with QGIS?

Comment: When I open any jpg or tiff, whether exported or not, in QGIS, it displays the rasters with the same blue-green tint, but viewing the same original jpg's in Windows viewer (or GIMP), the original color bands are intact. In other words, the terrain, vegetation, etc in the original appear as natural colors, until they are opened and viewed in QGIS or exported as geotiff rasters. Not sure why this is happening...

Comment: Have a look at layer-properties-symbology. Set contrast enhancement to "No". Does it change anything?

Comment: One other note: QGIS shows the layer properties as 3 bands, but strangely enough, it has no values for Band 1 - it is blank, whereas gdalinfo shows Band 1's data.

Comment: Contrast enhancement is already set to none...

Comment: Odd indeed. Can you share a test image?

Comment: Ok...to have the raster properly display the rgb bands, I added a Band 1 (initially blank in QGIS) in the layer's properties. Didn't enter any data for Band 1, but just noticed that it had what looks like incorrect entries already populated. Bands 2 and 3 were ok in QGIS.

Comment: Images are appearing properly now - Thanks for the tips!